# How to decrypt .ZC1PR and .XXFD formats after Ransomeware attack?

Tags: encryption, decryption

My company NAS has been attacked by Ransomeware and all the files are now encrypted to above file formats. Does anyone know any method of decrypting at least some files?

I can find some decryption tools for older ransomware attacks. But unfortunately, I couldn't find any tool for these file formats.

Thank you.

Comment: Try looking at https://www.nomoreransom.org. If you can't find a decryptor for the ransomware you have, then you can only restore from backups or pay.